# Access class in parent window with mootools

Tags: class, mootools, selector

I have something like
v = $$('.module');
and then code that accesses objects inside this v variable, and it worked, but...

I had to move the whole thing inside a popup (mootools new Window) but the element with class module has remained in the main page.

Is there any way to select the element with class module in the main page and not in the popup window???
thank you,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

```
$(parent.document.body).getElements('.module')
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Element.getFirst](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3agetFirst)? This will get the first element that matches a slector.

You could also try adding an id to your element if you want to select only that element?